# How to approximate this spiral curve

Tags: edit-mode

I am looking to replicate this curve in which my attempt was to use Math XYZ. However, I could not find a way to create a "constant thickness" around each of the spirals. Ie, a duplicate and scale smaller does not give the desired constant. Any suggestions are welcome. Ultimately I would like it to be a closed mesh.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. The Spirals**

Try the add-on *Add Curve: Extra Objects* that comes with Blender. Add a *Curve > Curve Spirals > Archemedian* curve and play with the settings in the popup to match the reference. Center the reference image and the curve at the world origin.
Then duplicate the curve twice and rotate the copies by 120°. Apply *All Transformations* to the curves.

[image: spiral curves]

**2. The Thickness**

Adding thickness is fairly easy with a little plane. Create a plane at the world origin (0,0,0), and add an *Array* and a *Curve* modifier. If it looks messed up then make sure you have applied *All Transformations* (<kbd>Strg</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in *Object* mode). Duplicate the plane twice and change the settings to align it along the other spirals.

Note: Curves can be beveled when by increasing the value of *Geometry > Bevel > Depth* on the *Object Data Properties* tab. But merging the resulting cylinders/pipes in the center is more complicated then.

[image: modifiers]

**3. The Clean Up**

Cut the extended spirals' ends in *Edit* mode. Then make a backup of the planes, apply the modifiers, and join three spiral meshes to one object. In *Edit* mode, merge (<kbd>M</kbd>) the vertex pairs to create the final mesh.

To maintain a quad mesh you can subdivide edges to create extra vertices, dissolve edges (<kbd>X</kbd>) and use the knife cut (<kbd>K</kbd>).

[image: merging vertices]

**Final mesh** (no math involved ;-)

[image: final mesh]

Comment: Somehow I cannot apply All Transforms to the 3 spiral curves. I get message "Rotation/Location cant apply to a 2d curve" even though I selected All Transforms

Comment: I see the problem: I selected 2d in the spirals window. I have another problem in that apply the fir curve via array makes the object look messed up. I have applied All Transforms at various stages.

Comment: Oh yes, the curve must be 3D. The Archemedian curve is 3D by default 3D. I just used your blend file. It works when I 1) add a plane at the 3D cursor (world origin), scale it down & apply the scale (or scale in *Edit* mode) 2) switch the curve to 3D 3) apply all transformations to the curve 4) add Array and Curve modifier to the plane and select the spiral in the settings (screenshot). It looks good then. 5) apply the *Array* modifier first, then the *Curve* modifier. The order is important. Then you have a spiral mesh with thickness. Repeat the steps with the other spirals for the final mesh.

Comment: I will try again later and let you know.